# Does anyone know what type of cactus this is?

Tags: cactus

[image: My Cactus]

Hi all,

I recently bought this cactus but haven't had much luck identifying it. Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is Euphorbia obesa

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/304415256036848192/

Comment: It's most likely a Euphorbia, but definitely not E. obesa.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be Orbea variegata, previously called Stapelia variegata

http://www.scoop.it/t/succulents?page=3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a cactus...
if you give it a tiny knick is the juice clear or milky?
clear would lean me to stapelia, milky to euphorbia...

it looks like a stapelia to me, generally, but the flower or the latex would be a more definitive test.